# Message could not be sent in ubuntu docker container, but succeed in ubuntu host

Tags: c#, ubuntu, docker, ironpython, smtpclient

I use the following code to send email in ubuntu16.04 with Mono/5.0.1.1.

```
from System.Net import NetworkCredential
from System.Net.Mail import *
from System.Net import ServicePointManager
from System.Net.Security import RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
def Send(server, port, username, password, sender, recipient, subject, body):    
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(lambda srvPoint, certificate, chain, errors: True)
    client = SmtpClient(server, port)
    client.EnableSsl = True
    credentials = NetworkCredential()
    credentials.UserName = username
    credentials.Password = password
    client.Credentials = credentials
    client.Timeout = 5000
    message = MailMessage(sender, recipient, subject, body)
    message.IsBodyHtml = True
    client.Send(message)
```

It succeeded in ubuntu16.04 host, but failed in docker container(ubuntu16.04) with the following exception:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message could not be sent. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket is not connected   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor (System.String hostname,
>   System.Int32 port) [0x0006d] in <8d14b500d75a425fb65c4de6134ed0a7>:0
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendInternal
>   (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message) [0x00006] in
>   <8d14b500d75a425fb65c4de6134ed0a7>:0    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message)
>   [0x00084] in <8d14b500d75a425fb65c4de6134ed0a7>:0

It may because the ubuntu docker image lack of some package to connect socket? But I can find the required package in ubuntu.

Is there any other reasons?

Cound anybody help me? thanks very much.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

By using below command, you can go inside docker ubuntu container

```
docker exec -i -t <container_name> bash
```

And then just try to troubleshoot, try to do it manually, once happy add those commands in your dockerfile.

Please let me know in case any issue with above command.